# Proving correctness of an exponentiation routine

Tags: correctness-proof, loops, software-verification

I have the following exponentiation routine, which takes $O(\log n)$ steps

```
function power(a:real, n:positive integer)
begin
  x:=1;
  i:=n;
  while i > 0 do
  begin
    if(i % 2 == 1) then   //i odd
      x:=x*a
    i:=floor(i/2)
    if(i > 0) then
      a:=a*a
  end;
  power:=x
end
```

**I'm trying to prove that it always gives $a^n$**.  I think it might be provable via induction on $n$.  in the examples i went through i found that it always ends with $i=1$ before the final division down to $0$.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @Raphael Seems clear to me: how to prove that the final value of `a` is $a^n$ where $a$ is the initial value of `a`. (The code is either missing `var` in front of `a:real` or should be a function that ends by returning `a`.)

Comment: @Gilles  It's a problem dump with some narrative about an approach. Where exactly is miniparser stuck? What do they need to know?

Comment: @Raphael Presumably stuck trying induction on $n$, which isn't an easy approach here. miniparser, you want a [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant); proving it will involve recursion on $i$.

Comment: @Raphael. As Gilles said, this reads as asking for a (hint to a) proof of program correctness, which is both clear and on-topic. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: input : $pow(a,n)$ and at each $k$th loop : $a_k = a^{2^k}$ (easy to prove) and if $i_k \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ with $i_k = \lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor$ then $x_k = x_{k-1} a_{k-1}$, otherwise $x_k = x_{k-1}$. at the end $x_n = \prod_{k, \  i_k \equiv 1 \pmod 2} a_k = a^{\sum_k 2^k(\lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor \% 2)} =  a^n$

Comment: i'm just trying to prove that the above code/pseudocode always produces $a^n$ as a result.  sorry if it is unclear.  there should probably be a return at end of function.  this is in contrast to simply looping from $1$ to $n$ and multiplying $a$ by itself which takes $O(n)$ steps.  thanks for the feedback.

Comment: miniparser please state more clearly how your attempt failes or what do you expect. As Raphael stated there is no question, just statements what you are doing. @reuns your comment looks more like answer.

Comment: @EvilJS : it is a sketch for an answer, but there is some work left to the OP, for understanding what I wrote and proving everything rigorously

Comment: @reuns yes, good hint, Gilles also hinted, so those are hint only answers, the OP (the most probably) wanted to lift off from some point to progress and finish.

Answer (score 3):

A standard approach to proving correctness of a program involving a loop is to use a loop invariant. Loop invariant $P(j)$ is a statement indexed by the iteration number $j$ (or a parameter related to the iteration number) that asserts a certain mathematical relationship between some variables appearing in your code. Proving $P(j)$ is true for all $j$ is typically done by induction. You show that $P(0)$ is true, i.e., the loop invariant is true prior to the beginning of the loop. You show that $P(i)$ is true implies $P(i+1)$ is true. Then you can conclude that the statement $P(n)$ (or $P(n+1)$) must be true, which asserts the relationship between the variables of interest that is directly relevant to the correctness of the algorithm. Note that if $j$ is some parameter related to the iteration number (e.g., $j$ could be $n$ minus the iteration number), the starting point and the direction of the induction might be different. Finding the right loop invariant is usually the hardest part.

Let's find a loop invariant for your code. Note that you overwrite the variable $a$ inside the loop. This means that I cannot use $a$ in the loop invariant to refer to the original input, but I'd like to. Therefore I introduce a new letter $\alpha$ to refer to the value of $a$ that is passed to the function, i.e., the first input. The rest of the variables are exactly as in your code. Our loop invariant $P(i)$ will be indexed by the variable $i$, which is related to the iteration number, but starts with $n$ and decreases to $0$ similar to what I wrote about above. Define the following loop invariant:
$$P(i) \text{ is true if and only if } x*a^i == \alpha^n$$
Clearly, at the beginning you have $x=1$,  $a=\alpha$, and $i = n$, so $P(n)$ is true. I leave proving the inductive step to you (note you will be proving $P(n)$ is true implies $P(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ is true, so this induction skips over lots of values, but it's okay - why?). When the algorithm terminates you have $P(0)$, which asserts $x*a^0 = \alpha^n$, i.e., $x = \alpha^n$, which is what you needed to prove.

Comment: it's ok for the induction to skip over values of $n$ because the induction is on the number of times the loop executes.